# count method returns different values depending on date in condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm running a query that looks at the number of days where an activity for a  record exists over the last three days (today included) in the database using the GroupBy gem to group them by day. Here is the full query:

```
Record.activities.where("created_at >= ?", 2.days.ago.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone).group_by_day(:created_at).count.count
```

2 days ago, I have 1 activity, yesterday I have 0 and today I have 2. This should return 2 (not 3, it's counting the days not the activities) but for some reason it returns 3. What's even stranger is that if I change `2.days.ago` to `1.day.ago` or `0.days.ago`, it returns the correct value, 1. It ignores yesterday where there were no activities and only counts the day (today) where it recognised there was an activity.

If I remove the second `.count`, here's what it returns for `2.days.ago`...

```
{Tue, 21 Nov 2017=>1, Wed, 22 Nov 2017=>0, Thu, 23 Nov 2017=>2}
```

and if I run it for `1.day.ago`, I get...

```
{Thu, 23 Nov 2017=>2}
```

Here is the raw SQL for the `2.days.ago` query..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', created_at) 
AS strftime_y_m_d_00_00_00_utc_created_at 
FROM "activities" 
WHERE "activities"."goal_id" = ? AND (created_at >= '2017-11-21 00:00:00') 
AND (created_at IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', created_at)
```

After some more testing, I noticed it only ignores a day with 0 activities if the x in `x.days.ago` falls on the day with 0. If there is more than 1 day with 0 activities, it will ignore the first one as it should but then count the other days with 0 that come after...

Not sure what I'm missing here but would appreciate any help finding the issue.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Why do you `count` twice?

Comment: Jut updated the question so you can see what the second one does but basically the second `count` counts the number of hashes returned.

Comment: My first impulse is that you are using count somewhere but you should be using sum.  If you add the raw MySQL query I can comment further.

Comment: Just updated the question to include the raw SQL

Comment: Does the raw query give you the expected results?

Comment: No, it seems to include the blank days except if the `x.days.ago` lands on a day with 0 activities. In that case, it will not count that day but will count any blank days after that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.having('count(activities.id) > 0')` to ignore days with no activity

untested query below:

```
Record.activities
  .select('count(activities.id) as count_all,date(activities.created_at) as day')
  .where("created_at >= ?", 2.days.ago.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone)
  .group('day').having('count_all > 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to return the right result but still curious to know why that initial query returns those results.

Here is the query that works:

```
Record.activities.where("created_at >= ?", 4.days.ago.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone).group_by_day(:created_at).count.reject {|k,v| v == 0 }.count
```

Comment: IMO, Its much more efficient to sort this in the SQL query by adding a filter to ignore rows with 0 count_all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your solution is not ok, because you need to make it in sql query (while you load all the data to ruby object and then sort them. It will be a bottle neck during scale). Just put the same thing to sql. I think this one should work:

```
Record.activities.where("created_at >= ? AND count_all > 0", 2.days.ago.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone).group_by_day(:created_at).count
```

Then about why you get 3 when you expect to get 2. Sql `COUNT(*)` returns number of rows. In your case you will always have 3 unique days, so 3 unique rows (group_by group them by their uniqueness). You must filter days with 0 count as I made in my query to filter rows, that have 0 in count, but still get counted